# Getopt in python

Tags: python, command-line, getopt

I am trying to read in a filename from the command line in python but for some reason it is saying '`getopt`' is undefined and I am unsure why.

```
filename=getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:])
```

I am new to python so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you `import getopt`? Also, you should really be using `argparse` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do several things:

- import getopt
- import sys
- Provide the options argument to getopt (2 arguments are required)

In the end your code will need to look something like (I don't know what options you want to recognize):

```
import getopt
import sys
filename=getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "f")
```